# Can I determine the rough frequency of an ac current by measuring the frequency of the electromagnetic radiation predominantly emitting from it?

Tags: ac, electromagnetism, skin-effect

Can I determine the rough frequency of an ac current by measuring the frequency of the electromagnetic radiation predominantly emitting from it? - if so, are there any other variable I need to consider, also how would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can definitely do that.

Since you're only looking for a signal, you don't need much coupling.  A coil held at right angle and close to the wire may be all you need for a pickup.

The ideal configuration is a toroidal core with the wire passing thru the loop, and the pickup wire wound around the toroid.  There are actually clip-on magnetic pickups for this purpose.  In that case, part of the magnetic core that goes around the wire to sense is movable.  The magnetic loop opens so that you can place it around the wire, then closes again to make good magnetic contact.  A bunch of turns of thin wire is wound around the stationary part of the magnetic core.  One place such devices are used is in strobe timing lights.  The magnetic pickup is clamped around a spark plug lead.

Current in the wire to be sensed causes a circular magentic field around it.  The magnetic core gives that field a nice place to go, thereby concentrating it.  The pickup wire is wound around a part of the magnetic core, acting like the secondary of a transformer.

You might be surprised what you can pick up with magnetic coupling.  Try winding a few 100 turns of magnet wire around a ferrite rod, then connect the two ends of the wire to the microphone input of a audio amplifier.  You'll be able to hear all kinds of things you might not expect as you move the coil close to anything with electric current in it.  Hold the coil to the earpiece of a telephone, and you can hear the whole conversation, for example.

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely! You can get the exact frequency that way, not just an estimate. You should take a look at [current transformers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Current_transformer) and combine one with a comparator and a [frequency counter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frequency_counter).

If you just hold a coil next to the wire, that might already be enough of a current transformer for your application. You can implement the frequency counter either in a microcontroller or with discrete TTL logic.

As Chris Stratton pointed out, harmonics and noise might cause the circuit to measure a wrong frequency. If that's the case, you can try to increase the coupling of the current transformer or filter out unwanted signals with a bandpass.

Comment: You can get the exact frequency of components.  However, which component is *strongest* in the radiated field may not be the same as the one which has the highest current flowing in the wire, since different frequencies will couple with different efficiency.